# When using the dynamic select that comes from the database, the button does not work

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

I'm developing an application that when you select the Doctor's name, it automatically pulls the specialty part that he attends from the database, and fills it out on its own, but when I use this function, basically my button to send the data to my other database it stops working, I don't know how to adjust

```
<?php

include('../conexao.php');
include('protect.php');

$sql = "SELECT id, nome, especialidade FROM medico";
$resultado = mysqli_query($mysqli, $sql);



if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{

  $medico = mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli, $_POST['medico']);
  $especialidade = mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli, $_POST['especialidade']);
  $ubs = mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli, $_POST['ubs']);
  $data = mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli, $_POST['data']);
  $turno = mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli, $_POST['turno']);
  
  
  $result = mysqli_query($mysqli, "INSERT INTO consulta (medico, especialidade, ubs, data, turno) 
  VALUES ('$medico', '$especialidade', '$ubs', '$data', '$turno')");
  
    }



?>


 <!DOCTYPE html>
 <html lang="en">
 <head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="/img/heart-pulse.svg"/>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap-icons@1.10.2/font/bootstrap-icons.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.0.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <title>Médicos - DoctorSystem </title>
 </head>
 <body>
 <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Doctor<b>System</b> <i class="bi bi-heart-pulse-fill"></i> </a>
  <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>

  <div class="container">
  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
    <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
      <li class="nav-item active">
        <a class="nav-link" href="painel.php"> <i class="bi bi-house-fill"></i> HOME</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="agenda.php"> <i class="bi bi-calendar-heart-fill"></i> AGENDA</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="pacientes.php"> <i class="bi bi-person-fill"></i> </i> PACIENTES</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="medicos.php"> <i class="bi bi-journal-medical"></i></i> MÉDICOS</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="consultas.php"> <i class="bi bi-journal-medical"></i></i> CONSULTAS</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0">
      <a href="#" class="nav-link disabled ">  </i> Bem vindo ao Painel, <?php echo $_SESSION['nome']; ?></a>
      <button class="btn btn-danger"> <a class="text-light"type="submit" href="logout.php"> <i class="bi bi-person"></i> Sair</a> </button>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
<br>
<div class="container">
<h2>Cadastrar <b>Consultas</b></h2>
<br>
<form action="consultas.php" method="POST">
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="medico">Médico:</label>
    <select class="form-control" id="medico" name="medico">
        <option value="">Selecione</option>
        <?php 
        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultado)) {
            echo "<option value='" . $row["nome"] . "'>" . $row["nome"] . "</option>";
        }
        ?>
    </select>
</div>


<div class="form-group">
  <label for="especialidade">Especialidade:</label>
  <select class="form-control" id="especialidade" name="especialidade"></select>
</div>
</form>

<!-- Script para lidar com a solicitação AJAX -->
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#medico').on('change', function() {
    var medico = $(this).val();
    $.ajax({
      url: 'especialidade.php',
      method: 'POST',
      data: {medico: medico},
      success: function(data) {
        console.log(data)
        $('#especialidade').html(data); // atualiza o conteúdo do select com as opções retornadas
      }
    });
  });
});

$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#submit').on('click', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault(); // impede o comportamento padrão do botão de envio
    console.log('Botão clicado'); // imprime uma mensagem no console para verificar se a função está sendo executada
    // adicione aqui o código para lidar com o envio do formulário usando AJAX
    var medico = $('#medico').val();
    var especialidade = $('#especialidade').val();
    var ubs = $('#ubs').val();
  });
});


</script>

  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="ubs">UBS:</label>
    <select class="form-control" id="ubs" name="ubs">
    <option value="">Selecione uma UBS</option>
    <option value="UBS MORUMBI - PASCHOAL ANGOTTI">UBS MORUMBI - PASCHOAL ANGOTTI</option>
    <option value="UBS RIBEIRO – DR. PÉRICLES DA SILVA PEREIRA">UBS RIBEIRO – DR. PÉRICLES DA SILVA PEREIRA</option>
    <option value="UBS REBOUÇAS – DR. NILTON NICOLAU NAUFAL">UBS REBOUÇAS – DR. NILTON NICOLAU NAUFAL</option>
    <option value="UBS JUNQUEIRA – DR. ADALBERTO ARIANO CRESPO">UBS JUNQUEIRA – DR. ADALBERTO ARIANO CRESPO</option>
    <option value="UBS CAIC DR - FRANCISCO MATHIAS ZORMAN">UBS CAIC DR - FRANCISCO MATHIAS ZORMAN</option>
    </select>
  </div>
  
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="data">Data da consulta:</label>
    <input type="date" class="form-control" id="data" name="data">
  </div>
  
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="turno">Turno:</label>
    <select class="form-control" id="turno" name="turno">
      <option value="">Selecione um turno</option>
      <option value="Manhã">Manhã</option>
      <option value="Tarde">Tarde</option>
      <option value="Noite">Noite</option>
    </select>
  </div>
  
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" name="submit" id="submit">Cadastrar Consulta</button>
</form>

</div>

 </html>
```

especialidade.php

```
<?php
// Conexão com o banco de dados
include('../conexao.php');
include('protect.php');

// Consulta SQL para obter a especialidade do médico selecionado
$medico = $_POST["medico"];
$sql = "SELECT especialidade FROM medico WHERE nome='$medico'";
$resultado = mysqli_query($mysqli, $sql);

// Cria uma variável para armazenar as opções do select
$options = '';

// Obtém as especialidades correspondentes e as adiciona à variável options
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultado)) {
  $options .= '<option value="' . $row["especialidade"] . '">' . $row["especialidade"] . '</option>';
}

// Retorna as opções correspondentes
echo $options;

// Fecha a conexão com o banco de dados
mysqli_close($mysqli);
?>
```

Basically it fills in by itself, but when I use this method via AJAX, the register button doesn't work

I already validated the connection with the bank and it's ok, I performed several tests and both ok

Answer (score 0):

You are calling `event.preventDefault()` in `$('#submit').on('click',` event handler, so your form is not submitted with the button, perhaps it can be submitted only by pressing *enter* in some input field.

Try commenting out `$('#submit').on('click',` (which apparently does *nothing*) to see if the system starts working

If the form submission sends to the containing PHP script (consultas.php) you can omit the action="consultas.php" attribute of the form

**One raccomandation:** use prepared statements with parameters in your queries, even in the query used in the ajax call

#### Further observations

You have closed the form before inserting the submit button: look at the *</form>* closing tag before the *<script>* section. There is another  closing tag after the *<button>* (that seems to be the right one)

See also that you have another <button> with attribute *type="submit"* and *href="logout.php"* in your page (Sair): remove that attribute, also because there is no space character between the *class* and *type* attributes

There would be other observations about the data, however the form should work now

Comment: I removed the part of "$('#submit').on('click'," but it remains the same, this part was just placed to test the button

Comment: @Victor I've added some additional content in my answer, look at **Further observations** section

Comment: It worked by adjusting the form

Comment: @Victor very good, if you appreciated my help then you can sign my answer as the sekected one  ;-)